# Saving and loading a trained GradientBoostingClassifier using joblib.dump

Tags: python, scikit-learn, save, load, ensemble-learning

I am trying to save a trained GradientBoostingClassifier using joblib.dump using the following code:

```
# use 90% of training data
NI=int(len(X_tr)*0.9) 
I1=np.random.choice(len(X_tr),NI)
Xi=X_tr[I1,:]
Yi=Y_tr[I1]

#train a GradientBoostingCalssifier using that data

a=GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=500, min_samples_leaf=50,presort=True,warm_start=True)

 a.fit(Xi,Yi) 

# calculate class probabilities for the remaining data

I2=np.array(list(set(range(len(X_tr)))-set(I1)))
Pi=np.zeros(len(X_tr))
Pi[I2]=a.predict_proba(X_tr[I2,:])[:,1].reshape(-1)

#save indexes of training data and the predicted probabilites
np.savetxt('models\\balanced\\GBT1\\oob_index'+str(j)+'.txt',I2)
np.savetxt('models\\balanced\\GBT1\\oob_m'+str(j)+'.txt',Pi)

# save the trained classifier
joblib.dump(a, 'models\\balanced\\GBT1\\m'+str(j)+'.pkl')
```

Once the classifier is trained and saved, I closed the terminal, opened a new terminal and run the following code to load the classifier and test it on the saved test dataset

```
    # load the saved class probabilities 
    Pi=np.loadtxt('models\\balanced\\GBT1\\oob_m'+str(j)+'.txt') 

    #load the training data index 
    Ii=np.loadtxt('models\\balanced\\GBT1\\oob_index'+str(j)+'.txt')

    #load the trained model
    a=joblib.load('models\\balanced\\GBT1\\m'+str(j)+'.pkl')

    #predict class probabilities using the trained model
    Pi1=a.predict_proba(X_tr[Ii,:])[:,1] 

    # Calculate aupr for the retrained model 
    _prec,_rec,_=metrics.precision_recall_curve(Y[Ii],Pi1,pos_label=1)
    auc=metrics.auc(_rec,_prec);

    # calculate aupr for the saved probabilities
    _prec1,_rec1,_=metrics.precision_recall_curve(Y[Ii],Pi[Ii],pos_label=1)
    auc1=metrics.auc(_rec1,_prec1);

     print('in iteration ', j, ' aucs: ', auc, auc1)
```

The code prints the following:
  in iteration 0 aucs: 0.0331879 0.0657821 
  ...............................
In all cases, the aupr for reloaded classifier is significantly different from the original trained classifier. I am using the same version of sklearn and python for loading and saving. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: save your model using pickle https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-gradient-boosting-models-xgboost-python/

Comment: Is the code correct? => `Ii=Pi=np.loadtxt...`. Here you are re-assigning the variable Pi with the indices you are loading.

Comment: @Paddy. Yes, he can. But the problem is unrelated, and also scikit docs [recommend to save scikit models with `joblib`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#persistence-example).

Comment: @Paddy I tried pickle.dump before trying joblib.dump. The same result.

Comment: @Vivek No sorry, that was the wrong code. Made a mistake when editing the code for this post (for clarity). I edited the code in the post now.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your code. I advise you split your data using `train_test_split`. It shuffles the data by [default](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

The code below produces the same result for `auc` metrics:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib

def main():
    X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=.3)

    clf = GradientBoostingClassifier()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    preds = clf.predict(X_test)
    prec, rec, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test, preds, pos_label=1)

    with open('dump.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(clf, f)

    print('AUC SCORE: ', auc(rec, prec))

    clf2 = joblib.load('dump.pkl')
    preds2 = clf2.predict(X_test)

    prec2, rec2, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test, preds2, pos_label=1)

    print('AUC SCORE AFTER DUMP: ', auc(rec2, prec2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```
>>> AUC SCORE: 0.273271889401
>>> AUC SCORE AFTER DUMP: 0.273271889401
```