# gradient boosting classifier save model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, save, classification, load

I trained GradientBoostingClassifier and saved like this

```
pickle.dump(clf,open("C:/Users/R2D2/Documents/Python/Supervised/TrainedModel.dat",'wb'))
```

and loaded the saved model like this

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open("C:/Users/R2D2/Documents/Python/Supervised/TrainedModel.dat",'rb'))
```

I get %94 accuracy on test data and only %50 on training data but after training these results were both %94 for training and test data. How can it change after saved?

[This look similar but doesn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953584/saving-and-loading-a-trained-gradientboostingclassifier-using-joblib-dump)

Comment: Silly question, are you passing the same data before and after you load the model? Also it is very strange that you get a largely higher accuracy in test than training

Comment: Yes using same data. Yes its strange after saving test doesn't change but training result is changing.

Comment: You can check whether the parameters stay the same using the method [`get_params`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.get_params).

Comment: get_params return same. More interestingly right after saving model i load saved model and i get same results for training and test data. but when i load model in different function it gives different results.